# excel vb , add current row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add the current active row to this formula in VB , where the 14 currently is, so that which ever row is active the row number will reflect

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F" & (ActiveCell.row)).Formula = "=SUM(E14*1,5)"
```

e.g, If `row 7` is active, then needs to be `E7`, automatically.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you tried this and it doesn't work? What about `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F" & (ActiveCell.row)).Formula="=E" & ActiveCell.row & "+5"`

Comment: yes this does work , I need an reference to active cell row in SUM(E14*1,5)

Comment: I added a suggestion to my comment above. It's the same principle.

Comment: thank you works great , but problem is when I try to multiply by 1,5     Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F" & (ActiveCell.row)).Formula = "=E" & ActiveCell.row & "*1,5"

Comment: Sorry didn't realise you were using comma for decimal point. Try replacing , with . for VBA.

Comment: Got it , just have to use an "." and not "," , thank you for the help

Comment: Can you put as an answer so I can give you the credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F" & (ActiveCell.row)).Formula="=E" & ActiveCell.row & "*1.5"
```